# CSS3 Box Shadow

Tags: css

I am using CSS3 property

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #CCCCCC;
```

Its giving this wierd effect on the right hand side and the bottom. 
How to make the shadow to be equal on all the sides ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #CCCCCC;
```

instead

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/nA7uw/1/)

The first two numeric values specify the relative x and y offset of the shadow. Hence your shadow was displaced/offset by a vector of (2px , 2px), or 2px right, and 2px down.

The third numeric value specifies the blur, and the fourth the shadow size/spread, and the fifth the colour (in HEX)

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #CCCCCC; /* Horizontal Length: px, Vertical Length: px, Blur Radius: px, Spread: px, Color */
```

You can test CSS3 here: http://css3generator.com/

Answer (score 4):

box-shadow is defined as: horizontal offset - vertical offset - shadow spread - blur size - color

You could just do: `box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ccc;`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting the first 2 values to 0px:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #CCCCCC;
```

See more: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)

Comment: what does the first to values refer to ?

Comment: The first: The position of the horizontal shadow. 
The second: The position of the vertical shadow.

Comment: checkout http://www.w3fools.com sometime.  While they can occasionally get information correct, I wouldn't trust them.